# How to deploy MongoDB, Socket.io Full-Stack Project

Tags: deployment, socket.io

I trying to deploy a project which i use mongodb nodejs expres and on client side pure javascript.

i deploy client side netlify and backend side render and cyclic.

Normaly it works buy when i implement socketio, and deploy on render is it not working, when trying to deploy cyclic, cyclic say websockets not supported.

Heroku is not free how can i deploy fullstack realtime app?

repos :

https://github.com/ozgurcoban01/nodejs-realtime-chatapp

https://github.com/ozgurcoban01/purejs-todolist-with-backend

Answer (score 0):

Add SSL to your http connection and it should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).